# Rotate dropdownlist

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select

Please have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rYtFQ/).

I'm trying to rotate the dropdownlist, but I was wondering if I could rotate the dropdownmenu as well.. When you click the dropdownlist now, a normal list appears, but I would like to have it rotated.

Thanks in advance for your solutions!

Comment: I'd be surprised if this is possible. A 'workaround' might be to use one of the many many stylized html dropdowns around the interwebs. Generally a combination of an input, button, and ul (all of which you can rotate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. The dropdowns from options are rendered by the system, and are as such not affected by your CSS selectors.

I suggest using a jQuery workaround, otherwise you're stuck using the "old-fashioned" option styles.